# Cannot find module "mysql" while running on heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku, cleardb

I have been trying to deploy my app on heroku.
I first used the command git push heroku master
and then running the node server using heroku run node server.js

However I get this error. Can anyone help me with this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdFbS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this error before using ibm db2... what you have to do is make a new directory locally, and login to Heroku using git in that new directory. once you do that, copy each folder and file into your new directory from your old one, (you can `cp ../olddirectory/app.js`,etc, etc)including the package.json and package-lock.json. once you do all that, push it, and it should work.

This sounds so stupid, but it works. every. freaken. time. I do this with all my projects as they all use db2. let me know if you need any more help.